# How to debug on server side in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to debug my code on the server side. Made the following changes in startup.batch:

```
set JPDA_ADDRESS=4666
set JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket

call "%EXECUTABLE%" jpda start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%
```

But after deploying the build , i get the following error on the console:

```
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - received >GET / HTTP/1.1< - except
ed >JDWP-Handshake<
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to connect to port 8080 - not 4666

Comment: no...i changed the port no to 4666. still its showing the same error

Comment: Erm, I don't understand your network - you have tomcat listening on port (8080?) for HTTP connections, and you're trying to debug Tomcat application from Eclipse or another IDE, pointing to remote host/4666. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

I don't  see anything wrong here  but to solve your problem please check below and try to debug on that port.

1. Port you are using for debug (maybe you have some other server blocking those ports).
2. The hostname of your computer (you may have localhost pointing somewhere in your host file or some configuration that makes it fail)